# When using PackageReference as RestoreProjectStyle, how do I avoid type exposure from transitive dependencies?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, transitive-dependency

- `ProjectA` references `ProjectB`
- `ProjectB` references `ProjectC`
- `ProjectA` has `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` in the .csproj

Given the above, it is possible to directly reference `ProjectC` types in `ProjectA`. This is undesirable since I don't want to leak types into `ProjectA`.

How can I avoid this compile-time automatic dependency inheritance / type exposure?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really at the moment. There are some workarounds like trying to change the references to a different namespace etc.

If you don't want some types to be instantiated by other assemblies, consider using `internal` constructors/types (along with `InternalsVisibleTo` assembly attributes for testing) or Roslyn analyzers to enforce usage rules.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue! Do you have a link to somewhere with more information about this? Or do you happen to know if there is a change planned to address this? I cannot actually change anything in ProjectC, since in my case that is actually Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

Comment: no, there is no plan. if the project in question would be the application hosting everything it would have needed a project reference as well, thus exposing all types. so the compiler now at least sees everything that's involved and the build system can resolve conflicts

Comment: What do you need links to? `InternalsVisibleTo`?

Comment: A link to something discussing this change. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't a reference to ProjectC from the hosting application unnecessary, since assembly resolving would load the necessary assemblies without actually exposing the types at compile time? So at runtime the types would be loaded correctly, but ProjectA (the hsoting application) couldn't make explicit references to the types in code

Comment: ... As long as none of the types in ProjectC are exposed in the public interface of ProjectB, of course.